# Keys match, but get/containsKey don't find it

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying retrieve a value from a hashmap. The keys are TransitionKey objects which have implemented equals and hashcode. When I use equals(...) to compare the key I want to look up and the current key in the hashmap, it returns true, but get returns null and containsKey returns false. I have not modified the key in any way since adding it to the hashmap. Can anyone help?

```
TransitionKey current  = new TransitionKey(this.currentState, inputSymbol);
    for(TransitionKey tk: transitions.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(tk.equals(current)); // True (only one key in table)
        System.out.println(transitions.containsKey(current)); // false
        String value = transitions.get(tk).toString(); // null
    }
```

In the TransitionKey class:

```
    /**
* @override
*/
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof TransitionKey)) return false;
    TransitionKey transitionKey = (TransitionKey) o;
    return (state.equals(transitionKey.state)) && (symbol==transitionKey.symbol);
}

/**
* @override
*/
public int hashcode() {
    int result = (int)symbol;
    result = result*31 + state.hashCode();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't overriden `hashCode`, you have created a new `hashcode` method (note the `c` vs. `C`).

Change your code to

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = (int)symbol;
    result = result*31 + state.hashCode();
    return result;
}
```

And it should work as expected.

Note that if you hadn't commented out the `@Override` annotation, you would have received a useful compiler error.

Comment: Thanks. My @override wasn't working either because I wasn't capitalizing the o...